# How to format this MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm having difficulty formatting this MySQL stored procedure, I've written SQL Server stored procedures but mysql keeps causing issues. Can anyone that has experience in this take a look and let me know what formatting I'm missing?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertPropertyAndUnit (
  IN AccountId INTEGER,
  IN Address VARCHAR(255),
  IN AddressNumber VARCHAR(255),
  IN City VARCHAR(255),
  IN State VARCHAR(255),
  OUT PropertyId INTEGER
)

BEGIN
  DECLARE PropertyId INTEGER;

  -- make property
  INSERT INTO tblProperties 
    (Address, AddressNumber, City, State)
  VALUES (
    IFNULL(Address, ''),
    IFNULL(AddressNumber, ''),
    IFNULL(City, ''),
    IFNULL(State, '')
  )
  SET PropertyId = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INTEGER)

  -- make a default unit
  INSERT INTO tblUnits (PropertyId, UnitNumber)
  VALUES (PropertyId, 1)

  -- Make an Accountpropertymembership
  INSERT INTO tblAccountPropertyMemberships (AccountId, PropertyId, MembershipRoleId)
  VALUES (AccountId, PropertyId, 0)

  SELECT PropertyId FROM tblProperties WHERE PropertyId = @PropertyId
END
```

Comment: Afaik, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is an MSSSQL-only thing; in MySQL you'd typically use last_insert_id() instead. Also, @variables are session variables and not the same as declared variables. So the latter inserts will be using a session variable with a value not determined by the procedure. Also, `;` is not optional in MySQL.... and I still think it is a crime MS made them optional to begin with.

Comment: Avoid using variables with the same names as table columns.

Comment: ...and what Barmar said; that goes for DECLAREd variables and proc parameter names. The @ prefix on session variables tends to make ambiguity with column names a non-issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to get the last auto-increment ID is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

You can't use `@PropertyID` to access a declared variable named `PropertyID`. Similarly, you can't use `@AccountID` to access the `AccountID` parameter.

You don't need to declare the variable `PropertyID`, since it's already declared as an `OUT` parameter.

You need `;` at the end of each statement. Use the `DELIMITER` directive to specify an alternate query delimiter, so you can use `;` within the procedure.

At the end, you can simply use `SELECT PropertyId` to return the value of the variable, you don't need to query the table itself.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertPropertyAndUnit (
  IN AccountId INTEGER,
  IN Address VARCHAR(255),
  IN AddressNumber VARCHAR(255),
  IN City VARCHAR(255),
  IN State VARCHAR(255),
  OUT PropertyId INTEGER
)

BEGIN
  PropertyId INTEGER;

  -- make property
  INSERT INTO tblProperties 
    (Address, AddressNumber, City, State)
  VALUES (
    IFNULL(Address, ''),
    IFNULL(AddressNumber, ''),
    IFNULL(City, ''),
    IFNULL(State, '')
  );
  SET PropertyId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  -- make a default unit
  INSERT INTO tblUnits (PropertyId, UnitNumber)
  VALUES (PropertyId, 1);

  -- Make an Accountpropertymembership
  INSERT INTO tblAccountPropertyMemberships (AccountId, PropertyId, MembershipRoleId)
  VALUES (AccountId, PropertyId, 0);

  SELECT PropertyId;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use CurPropertyId instead of PropertyId in a couple of places?

Comment: I had an intermediate version of the procedure that renamed the variable, but I changed it back and missed some occurrences.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! Those explainations were wonderful and were a pain to not realize. I did accidentlaly leave the "@" by accident when I was messing with things, sorry about that.